# Strange error : "error loading plugin. The specified module could not be found"

Tags: qt

I try to load my plugin using this code :

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0);
QPluginLoader loader(path);
AnprPluginInterface *i = qobject_cast< AnprPluginInterface* >(loader.instance());
if (i == NULL )
    QMessageBox::information(0, "this", "error loading plugin." + loader.errorString());
else
    QMessageBox::information(0, "this", "plugin loaded.");
```

I send the absolute path of plugin to `QPluginLoader` but it says that can't find the plugin !
Error is :

```
error loading plugin. "Cannot load library The specified module could not be found."
```

Comment: See this for tips in debugging plugin issues: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-plugins.html#debugging-plugins

Comment: @Mat ~> Thank you. Your link solved the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you sure that your plugin is exporting the correct interface using the Q_INTERFACES() macro? If you get the error you have two possible things to check:

1) loader.instance() returns 0: in that case you have to investigate on the reported error.

2) qobject_cast returns 0: in that case I suppose that the problem is in the missing exported interface.

Also, you should consider that both of your execution paths are executing the same code, so maybe you're not getting an error at all... I'm referring to this:

```
if (i == NULL )
    // Reports the error
    QMessageBox::information(0, "this", "error loading plugin." + loader.errorString());
else
    // Hey!? WTF!? Repots the error anyway!?
    QMessageBox::information(0, "this", "error loading plugin." + loader.errorString());
```

3) I was forgetting: also check if both the plugin and the application are being built in the same way (debug/release).

4) By the way, another thing that should be checked is if the plugin carries some dependency (other dynamic libraries, for example). It happened to me once and I spent quite some time before figuring out that I was missing a DLL and that was preventing my plugin to load correctly!

Comment: Oh what a silly mistake ! anyway thank you. 3rd ! option + Mat's link helped :D

Comment: Can you provide more details about the fourth option? I don't know how to link my dependency library to let my plugin loaded properly.